# Displaying Pictures in Array

Tags: java, arrays, image

In drjava I'm trying to acquire pictures in hold them in the array, and then print out a description of each picture. Right now everything compiles but when I run it has me choose the folder that contains the pictures and then the interactions pane disappears. The code I have so far is in my House app for acquiring the pictures and printing the descriptions is

SSCCEE

HOUSE.java

```
public class House
{
  String owner;
  public final static int CAPACITY = 6;
  Picture[ ] pictArray = new Picture[CAPACITY];

  public House(String pString)
  {
    this.owner = pString;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return("The House owned by " + this.owner);
  }
  public void acquire( int position, Picture pRef )
  {
    this.pictArray[ position ] = pRef;
  }
  public void printPictures()
  {
    for (int i=0; i < this.pictArray.length;i++)
    {
      System.out.print("The Picture in position " + i + " is ");
      System.out.println( this.pictArray[ i ]);
    }
  }
  public void swap( int positionA, int positionB )
  {
    System.out.println("NOTHING DONE.  THIS IS JUST A swap's STUB");

  }
  public void showOff()
  {
    System.out.println("NOTHING DONE.  THIS IS JUST showOff's STUB");

  }
}
```

Test.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] a)
  {
    House h = new House("Justin Chaisetseree");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    FileChooser.pickMediaPath();
    for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
      h.acquire(i,new Picture(FileChooser.pickAFile()));
    }
    h.printPictures();
    h.showOff();
    Boolean done = false;
    while( ! done )
    {
      System.out.println("Which two do you want to swap?");
      System.out.print("Type in two numbers from 0 to ");
      System.out.print( 5 );
      System.out.println(" or two -1s to stop.");
      int userInput1 = sc.nextInt();
      int userInput2 = sc.nextInt();
      if( userInput1 < 0 || userInput2 < 0)
      {
        done = true;
      }
      else
      {
        h.swap( userInput1, userInput2 );
      }
    }
    h.showOff();      
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556). 3) *"the interactions pane disappears"*  What 'interactions pane'?!?  That statement alone implies to me a GUI, whereas the code snippets above are more typical of an app. run from the command line.  Point 1 X 1000 - post an SSCCE.

Comment: I guess I was unclear. I can set the mediapath, but then I cannot choose the picture files. An interactions icon remains open on my Dock but isnt really there, and when I hover over Interactions in drjava its just perpetually loading

Comment: *"I guess I was unclear."*  That makes two of us.  Which part of *"For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)."* do you **not** understand?

Comment: Sorry, I am new at this and thought my problem might have been solved easier. I think I edited it so that it is an "SSCCEE"

Comment: *"I think I edited it so that it is an "SSCCEE""*  Think again.  An SSCCE has only one source file and no more than one `public` class in that file.  Further, if I change the code to be that way, it ***still*** shows compilation errors.  Please make use of the SSCCE Text Based Compiler to ensure that an SSCCE of a run-time problem actually compiles cleanly!

Comment: I do not know how to make it work by putting them all in a single file. The two seperate files compile for me but oh well thanks anyway.

Comment: *"The two seperate files compile for me.."*  That is probably because you have defined a `Ship` class in your IDE.  Try pulling your head out of your IDE for a minute, and stepping way back from the problem - way back.  To do that, try the following.  Create a new project in your editor.  Copy/paste that code you posted.  Compile it!